# Insert phtml in custom CMS page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, cms, phtml

i had created a new module on Magento 2.
It have:

setup -> `UpgradeData.php` :

```
    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        /**@var \Magento\Cms\Model\Page $page */
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1') < 0) {
            $page = $this->_pageFactory->create();
            $page->setTitle('Voucher CMS')
                ->setIdentifier('voucher-cms')
                ->setIsActive(true)
                ->setPageLayout('1column')
                ->setStores(array(0))
                ->setContent('{{block class="Cincuenta\\Voucher\\Block\\Product\\View\\Extra" block_id="voucher-cms" template="Cincuenta_Voucher::voucher/voucher.phtml"}}
')
                ->save();
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
```

It creates well my new CMS with the content.

I had a phtml on view -> frontend -> templates -> voucher -> `voucher.phtml`:

```
<h1> Test Voucher</h1>
```

and Block - Product -View - `Extra.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Cincuenta\Voucher\Block\Product\View;


class Extra extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
{

}
```

Code on my CMS:

```
{{block class="Cincuenta\\Voucher\\Block\\Product\\View\\Extra" block_id="voucher-cms" template="Cincuenta_Voucher::voucher/voucher.phtml"}}
```

But when i try to see my H1 in my CMS, it don't give me nothing, but a few times gives me an error that i was calling a wrong block.

Comment: what are you try to say?

Comment: The phtml isn't showed in my CMS page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine. However, you said that your `.phtml` file is

`view -> templates -> voucher -> voucher.phtml`

Ideally, it should be here:

`view -> frontend -> templates -> voucher -> voucher.phtml`

Comment: Sorry , i forgot the frontend, but it was there created.
So, why i couldn't see nothing?

Comment: Dunno how but it get solved with the same code today just changing my block_id to 'vouchercms' instead of 'voucher-cms' . Dunno what was the problem, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First run command.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

You have to write below code inside cms page,

```
{{block class="Cincuenta\Voucher\Block\Product\View\Extra" template="Cincuenta_Voucher::voucher/voucher.phtml.phtml"}}
```

Remove var folder and check again.

Comment: If you see, i had the same code inserted in my content of CMS in my UpgradeData.php .
I run the command to update my changes all times so that is not the problem.

Comment: Have you tried using above code in your cms page?

Comment: what you mean? Use code on my CMS content page?

Comment: yes you have to define in cms content page to display inside your cms page

Comment: I had already this line of code on my content page. See my UpgradeData.php and my setContent()